# Kendo UI DateTimePicker does not bind properly into the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a complex object that I need to pass to the controller when submitting a form.  This complex object has an object and a list of objects.  This is my Web API controller that receives the complex object via post with ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreatePurchaseInvoice(NewPurchaseInvoice newPurchaseInvoice)
{
    try
    {
        var purchaseInvoice = new PurchaseInvoice
        {
            Id = newPurchaseInvoice.PurchaseInvoice.Id,
            DatePurchaseInvoice = newPurchaseInvoice.PurchaseInvoice.DatePurchaseInvoice
        };

        // Here i do other stuff with the list of objects   

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Ok();
 }
```

This is my html form:

```
<form id="purchaseInvoiceForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Order:</label>
            <select id="numberOrder" class="form-control" required name="numberOrder">
                <option value="">Select an order number...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date of Purchase Invoice:</label><br />
                <input id="datePurchaseInvoice" style="width: 70%" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    //Here i have an html table and every row i push into an array of the complex object
</form>
```

And this is my jQuery code where i send the complex object via ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //this is the declaration of my complex object
    var newPurchaseInvoice = {
            PurchaseInvoice: {},
            PurchaseInvoiceDetails: []
    }


    $("#purchaseInvoiceForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        newPurchaseInvoice.PurchaseInvoice= {
            Id: $("#numberOrder").val(),
            DatePurchaseInvoice : $("#datePurchaseInvoice").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/purchaseInvoices",
            method: "post",
            data: newPurchaseInvoice
        });
    });
});
```

The problem I have is that the date of the KendoDateTimePicker is not sending correctly to the controller. 
I get this date and not the one I select with the kendoDateTimePicker. This is the DatePurchaseInvoice property of my PurchaseInvoice model in spanish:

[image]

This is my KendoDateTimePicker for jQuery:

```
$("#datePurchaseInvoice").kendoDateTimePicker({        
    value: new Date(),
    dateInput: true
});
```

And this is my NewPurchaseInvoice model:

```
public class public class NewPurchaseInvoice 
{
    public PurchaseInvoice PurchaseInvoice{ get; set; }
    public List<PurchaseInvoiceDetail> PurchaseInvoiceDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my PurchaseInvoice model:

```
 public class PurchaseInvoice 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePurchaseInvoice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Date` is not what is getting posted.. `DatePurchaseInvoice` is..   what is the actual property name on `NewPurchaseInvoice`

Comment: You should post your NewPurchaseInvoice model and PurchaseInvoice model code

Comment: I edited my post now. Thanks for your reply

Comment: What is the actual value your sending, and what is the culture on the server?

Comment: the culture that is defined in the bundle class is "~/Scripts/kendo/cultures/kendo.culture.es-ES.min.js", and the value that i want to send is the default value: new Date() or the one that i pick in the kendo widget

Comment: Yes but is the culture on the server also `es-ES`? And I mean what is the actual value your sending when it fails - its it all dates, or only when you pick a date with a day greater that 12?

Comment: now that you mention it doesn't work in dates with days greater than 12, I don't know why the months it takes as days and vice versa. I had to format it: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" to make it work, I don't know how in other forms I did not have this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specifying the type of data you are supplying:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

And possibly dataType too [depending on your response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-between-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function).  And [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000602/231716), you may need to stringify your response.  I don't think I've needed to do that but I don't often use AJAX operations for complicated data types.

Comment: still does not work with the dates, I think it has to be some problem with kendo. all other data I want to send to the controller are sent correctly but not so with the date.

Comment: Oh also yeah I didn't realize, to get the date out of the control, does val() work because you could also use the API: `$("#datePurchaseInvoice").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value()`